# What do these matrices converge to?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Sorry this is quite a specific question, happy to reword the title however you think is more appropriate, but for a given $m$ x $n$ matrix A, and an initial, random $n$ x $k$ matrix $v$, I have this loop which calculates:

```
U = A*V; 
[U,UR] = qr(U,0);
V = A'*U;
[V,VR] = qr(V,0);
```

until $|UR-VR|\approx0$

I understand that UR and VR are diagonal matrices where the *i*th diagonal entry stores the norm values relating the *i*th column of U and V respectively,  which are unit vectors.

But I'm confused as to why there is convergence other than the circular relationship between $U$ and $V$, and also how they are  significant.

Any pointers  would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are asking for tracks helping to understand what this algorithm is made for, here is a  **partial, mainly experimental, answer.**

First of all : let us recall that Matlab instruction [Q,R]=qr(M) gives "the" QR factorization $M=QR$ of matrix $M$ into an orthogonal matrix $Q$ and an upper triangular matrix $R$.

> Experimental constatation : the absolute values of the entries of diagonal matrices $UR, VR$ always converge to the **singular spectrum** (set of singular values) of $A$. Moreover, matrix $V$ converges to the matrix of singular vectors that is found in svd decomposition $A=USV^T$.

The eigenvalues of matrix A^TA are known to be the singular values of $A$.

Here is a computation done with the notations of the Matlab program below (expanding - with different notations - the 4 lines given by the asker) showing how the symmetrical matrix $A^TA$ is involved in the algorithm.

$$\begin{cases}U_i&=&AV_i&\\
Q_iR_i&=&AV_i & \ \text{By left-multiplying LHS and RHS by } \ A^T \ : \\
A^TQ_iR_i&=&A^TAV_i &\\
WR_i&=&(A^TA)V_i & \\
(V_{i+1})(S_{i}R_i)&=&(A^TA)(V_i) & \\
\end{cases}$$

In the hypothesis where $R_i$ and $S_i$ close to (identical) diagonal matrices (which in fact they tend to be), we find a version of the power iteration algorithm (http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Power_Iteration) for symmetric matrices. But I am conscious that this is not a rigorous approach.

I attempted also to approach, unsuccessfuly, a version of the so-called QR algorithm ("without shifts") for computing eigenvalues of $A^TA$ : see for this method, the excellent slideshow

https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/csci5304/FILES/LecN13.pdf

Appendix : Here is the equivalent program on which I have been working (with a fixed number of steps) :

> ```
> m=4;n=3;k=5;
> A=2*rand(m,n)-1; % in order to have negative and positive entries
> V=2*rand(n,k)-1;
> for q=1:50;
>    U = A*V;
>    [Q,R] = qr(U,0);
>    W = A'*Q;
>    [V,S] = qr(W,0);
> end;
> U,V, % with R1 (almost) identical to R2
> [U1,S,V1]=svd(A); % (almost) identical to the set abs(diag(R1))
> ```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! I can see some of the parallels between your code and mine, though I'd note that w.r.t. Matlab's qr code, my example actually calls the "economy-sized decomposition" where, "If m > n, only the first n columns of Q and the first n rows of R are computed. If m<=n, this is the same as [Q,R] = qr(A)." (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qr.html). Also in my case A is not symmetric as it is not square!

Comment: I noticed that you use qr factorizations for matrices that _could be_ rectangular, but I hadn't thought that they are never square...

Comment: In fact, following your remark, I have completely revised my answer : the convergence is toward the **singular spectrum** (svd(A)) of $A$ that doesn't need anymore to be neither square nor symmetrical !

Comment: Besides, can I ask you where you have found this algorithm/program ?

Comment: OK, so u and v are the left/right singular vectors of A? Do you know any references for this so I can read up? Definitely, still confused haha. The program was in a problem set of mine!

Comment: About columns of $U$ and $V$ being singular vectors, a closer look seems necessary, but it should be around such a result...

Comment: What I find is that $V$ found by the algorithm is the "good" $V$ of svd decomposition  $A=U\Sigma V^T$ but $U$ isn't the good one. But having $V$ is enough...

Comment: Is it enough to recreate A?

Comment: Why would it be necessary to re-create $A$ (in my version at least) ?

Comment: The question is framed in a way that suggests that the code in question can efficiently compress A, without having to compute the svd directly

Comment: I see. I will continue working on this interesting issue ( I have added to my text the fact that $AA^T$ "has to be in the loop" ; no pun intended )